# SSAS/SSRS - Dimensionsecurity and Subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

we have a few of SSAS-Cube-based reports that are displayed via SSRS-Webportal.
We used dimension security, windowsauthorization and it works fine. (MS SQL Server 2016)

My question: Now we need additionally subscriptions for these reports. What is Best-Practice to realize this?

My idea:

1) Leave the old reports for display in ssrs-portal

2) Copy each report and generate a mandatory ID like @prmCustomerID in each report. Use a saved Windowslogin for identity change in each report. Use the @prmCustomerID in MDX for select the displayed Data in report. Deploy these reports into a "admin"-folder on SSRS.

3) Add a datadriven Subscription for each report and fill the @prmCustomerID.

What annoys me is, that every report exists in duplicate.
How do you do this? What is best practice?

Thanks for any idea, Andrea